# I can not find scanner (brother DSmobile700D) driver for Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, scanner, brother

I want to install brother DSmobile-700D drivers in Ubuntu 12.04.

I visited brother's website but I was not able to find the driver.
[link to DSmobile-700D driver download site](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=ds700d_all)
They ask what OS I am using, but only offer Windows and OSX.

How can I get my scanner to work anyway?

Comment: Results of `sudo sane-find-scanner -v -v` ? You probably need to create a topic here http://sane.10972.n7.nabble.com/SANE-Dev-f3.html to request support for it (and include the results of the command). Or have someone tell you the nearest supporterd driver.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your scanner is unsupported in Linux:

- no manufacturer support,
- [no SANE back-end support](http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-mfgs-cvs.html#Z-BROTHER)